# routing a webpage error, nodejs and expressjs

Tags: node.js, express, routes, backend

I am trying to route directly to the html file using express.js, getting an unknown error, being new to express.js, I couldn't get how to resolve this one:-

**here is the js code :-**

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require();
const app = express();

const port=process.env.PORT || 8000;

// public static path
const static_path = path.join(__dirname,"../public");

app.use(express.static(static_path));


app.get("",(req,res)=>{
  res.send("welcome to this main page");
})

app.get("/about",(req,res)=>{
    res.send("welcome to this about page");
  })

  app.get("/weather",(req,res)=>{
    res.send("welcome to this weather page");
  })

app.get("*",(req,res)=>{
    res.send("404 Error page oops");
  })

app.listen(port,()=>{
    console.log(`listening to the port ${port}`);
})
```

**static web page:-**
**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Weather App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Welcome to the static web</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

**getting this error:-**

```
internal/validators.js:124
    throw new ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE(name, 'string', value);
    ^

TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "id" argument must be of type string. Received undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

ok, I was using "type nul > filename" command for creating new files in attached folders. When I used directly the VSCode feature of creating files, it's working fine now,... don't know why, but I think that old command might have expired, tell me if I am wrong, but I just solved my issue...